# Discussion Forum 3.1.15 - This form has expired

Tags: ee2, ee2-upgrades, forum

I'm on EE 2.8.1 and Discussion Forum 3.1.15 and when I try unsubscribe from forum threads I get this error message: *This form has expired. Please refresh and try again.*

I tried to updated the config.php file with the info on this thread without success: 
[Error After Install](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/20686/error-after-install/20733#20733)

Is this an EE bug that can be fixed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add 
$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y";

to your config file, you need to add the XID to the form in a hidden field to get rid of the error the other way.

Comment: *$config['disable_csrf_protection'] = "y";*

worked for me with a similar issue I had with Exp:resso Store where occasional product pages showed *form has expired*.  I also had this line in my v2.10.2 config.php file, which didn't seem on its own to work:

*$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;*